# PHP Twitter search api with tweet back button

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using working on building a WordPress plugin, that uses the Twitter api - but I'm very new to working with Twitter.

I currently have a keyword search form and results working

```
<?php

// get the keyword from url
$srchterm = $_GET['search_box'];

// encode it for the safe search
$srchterm = urlencode($srchterm);

// search the keyword using Twitter API
$srch_twitts = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=".$srchterm."";

// use curl to execute the Twitter URL
$twits = curl_init();
curl_setopt($twits, CURLOPT_URL, $srch_twitts);
curl_setopt($twits, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$twi = curl_exec($twits);

// here we have the searched result in an array
$search_res = new SimpleXMLElement($twi);

//print_r($search_res);

?>
<?php

/* display the data */

$i = 0;

// displays the search keyword
echo "<p style='padding-left:10px; color:brown'>Your search term is: " . stripslashes($_GET['q']) . "</p>";

// tweets in an array. split it by foreach
// we need only 10 result so, use if condition
foreach ($search_res->entry as $result) if ($i++ < 10)
{

echo "<div id='tweets'>";
echo "<p>$i</p> ";
echo "<div class='avatar'><img src='". $result->link[1]->attributes()->href. "' /> </div>";
echo "<div class='twitcont'>";
echo "<div class='name'>". $result->author->name . "</div>";
echo "<div class='content'>" . $result->content ;

// convert the updated date of tweet to seconds
$twittedSeconds = time() - strtotime($result->updated);
$names = array('second', 'minute', 'hour', 'day', 'week', 'month', 'year');
$seconds = array( 1,        60,       3600,   86400, 604800, 2630880, 31570560);

// find the time difference between present time and tweet time

if($twittedSeconds > 0)
{
for($j = count($seconds) - 1; $j >= 0 ; $j--)
{
$interval = $seconds[$j];
if($twittedSeconds >= $interval)
{
$getTime =  round($twittedSeconds / $interval);
if ($getTime > 1)
{
$names[$j] .= s;
}
$time = $getTime. ' ' . $names[$j] . ' ago';
break;
}
}
//echo the time difference
echo "<div class='time'> " . $time . "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
echo "</div></div>";

}

?>
```

**My question:**
How can I integrate a tweet button for each result - this would allow the admin to (after searching twitter for keyword matches) tweet back on conversations.

Please see this example: http://screencast.com/t/2xBkTyUHT

Comment: What does this back button do? `retweet` or `reply` ?

Comment: Yes I did - thanks a lot it worked perfectly: I have one more question - How would I add the "Retweet" button, in the case this becomes necessary. –

Comment: Did you read [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents)? there is retweet api too. If this works for you. Please accept the answer.

Comment: I had never heard of this Web Intents - thanks, I'm going to check it out.

I'll mark question as answered, you have been a fantastic help.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the tweet id then attach a hyper link of this format

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to={tweet id}
```

So the link might look like this.

```
$tweet_id = substr($entry->id, strrpos($entry->id, ':')+1);
echo "<a href=\"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to={$tweet_id}\">Reply</a>";
```

More information can be found here. [Twitter Web Intents](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents)

Note: You put `echo "<div id='tweets'>";` in a loop. Means DOM will have multiple elements with same id.  Correct it either using `class`  or put it outside the loop.

Comment: I have one more question - How would I add the "Retweet" button, in the case this becomes necessary.

Comment: Just noticed that the tweet is only going to my account (not the tweet id )

Comment: When you reply you write something against the tweet. hence the *tweet id* is needed. And its your reply so it'll be actually your tweet but with `@user` in front and there will be a `in reply to` link. To construct the link *tweet id* is needed

Comment: the twitter id is not showing in the url - here is what show when I hit reply: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=&original_referer=

reply_to={$tweet_id} (is empty in url)